# Send custom data to endpoint based on checkbox value via webforms POST handler

Tags: 8, webforms

Drupal 8.9, webforms 5.x

I'm trying to send some text data to a endpoint on form submission via a POST handler. It's based on the value of a (single) checkbox on a webform. The endpoint only accepts specific text values, so I need to somehow convert the 0/1 to those specific text values - if checked => "Signed up", else => "Not signed up".

I want the equivalent of

```
"key": [webform:elements:checkbox_machine_name:checked] ? "Signed up" : "Not signed up"
```

if you could have a ternary in the yaml format...

Is there a way I can do this via webforms?

I'm happy to install more modules, but if possible I'd like to avoid writing any PHP...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a Computed Twig element to execute the ternary operator and set the value in the remote post data.

@see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rRlTTkwdP_o

Comment: This looks exactly like what I want, thanks. Am just having a little trouble getting it working though - `{{ data.checkbox_name.checked ? 'Signed up' : 'Not signed up' }}` seems to always evaluate to 'Not signed up'. Is anything obviously wrong?

Comment: I found it - `.checked` is not a thing. Not sure where I got that from..